# Conditionally render tags to different views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Am using a view with table (simple html tags) one like below to render in to two different views.

This table is inside MVC views>shared folder so does indicating its used by two different views.

View-1 needs all columns to display; But view-2 doesn't need column "Delete". How to conditionally render this shared (table-view) view showing only columns that the asking view needs?

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="min-width: 100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>ItemDesc</th>
        <th>UM</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Delete</th> /*View-2 don't need this*/
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

  @foreach (var model in Model){
    data goes here for respective <th> as <td> by getting from a model
        <td>model.Item</td>
        <td>model.ItemDesc</td>
        <td>model.UM</td>
        <td>model.Qty</td>
        <td>model.Category</td>
        <td>model.Comment</td>
        <td>model.Delete</td> /*View-2 don't need this*/
   }
</tbody>
```

How to do this in ASP MVC 5 views?

Comment: Are you using a view model? If so add a property such as  `public bool CanDelete { get; set; }` that can be set in the controller and used by the view

Comment: am using one(same )model for both view-1 and view-2

Comment: @flute...just try answer given below...

Comment: So in the method that returns View1, set `CanDelete=true;` and in the method that returns View2, set `CanDelete=false;1 (its the default so probably net necessary), then `@if(model.CanDelete){...` add respective `th` and `td` elements when constructing `thead` and `tbody` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store a token value inside Viewbag or Tempdata as :

```
@Viewbag.show="no";

if(@Viewbag.show!="no"){
   <td>model.Delete</td>
}
else{
    <td></td>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is pass the additional information in the modal of the view like this

```
         if(modal.EnableDelete)
             <td>Delete</td>
```